# Exporting data from database to text file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in my database called Employeee.
I need to write the database data to a file. 
How do I do it in asp.net mvc C#?
i have tried Datatable approach,but it failed.

Comment: on controller side just put data inside datatable and put that datatable inside viewbag and then typecast that viewbag back to datatable inside view

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to make it answerable. Please show the code you tried and describe specific issues with this code. "it failed" is definitely not a good description. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Do It the same way you would do in a winform, wpf or so.

For example, if your text document has to be in JSON, use :

```
using(TextWriter writer = new TextWriter(@"yourfilename.json")){
    writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Employeee));
}
```

In my example, don't forget to import the `Newtownsoft.Json` package.

You can also formate everything in [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)...